# Calculated column based on secondary key in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

My data looks somewhat like this:

| key | city | currentCityKey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Boston | NaN |
| 2 | New York | 1 |
| 3 | Concord | 2 |

I'd like to create a new column with the current city name, which needs to be found by finding the city that corresponds to the currentCityKey value, returning this:

| key | city | currentCityKey | currentCity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Boston | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | New York | 1 | Boston |
| 3 | Concord | 2 | New York |

I've tried a lot of things, but I run into problems trying to return the value from the city column. This should just be a  simple if currentCityKey is notnull then city where currentCityKey == key, but I just can't seem to get from this logic to actual code.

Raw input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': [1, 2, 3],
 'city': ['Boston', 'New York', 'Concord'],
 'currentCityKey': [nan, 1.0, 2.0]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapper with the `'key'` and `'city'` columns and use `map` on `'currentCityKey'` column to obtain `'currentCity'` column:

```
df['currentCity'] = df['currentCityKey'].map(df.set_index('key')['city'])
```

Output:

```
   key      city  currentCityKey currentCity
0    1    Boston             NaN         NaN
1    2  New York             1.0      Boston
2    3   Concord             2.0    New York
```